# How to use QUERYSTRING, Cookies, GET/POST methods in a python cgi script?

Tags: python, html, cgi, dynamic-html

I am writing a Quiz app using python Script. My HTML file Contains 1 Question at a time Displayed along with its 4 options. Below there are 2 buttons for Questions to Navigate. "Previous" and "Next". once the option is chosen, user can click next button and the selected value should be stored somewhere for further calculation of score and next Question
should be displayed.

I am new to Cgi stuff. So far i am able to load Question 1. and i am stuck further.
Somebody please help

i am storing questions and options in a seperate file like this
question|optionA|optionB|optionC|optionD|answer

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi, Cookie, os, cgitb, linecache

cgitb.enable()

cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()

attempt = 0
qc= 0
scr = 0
wrng = 0
total = 0
cur = 1

cookie["Attempted"] = attempt
cookie["Correct"] = qc
cookie["Score"] = scr
cookie["Wrong"] = wrng
cookie ["Count"] = total
cookie["Current"] = cur

file = "quest" # my question bank

data = linecache.getline(file,cur)
data = data.strip('\n')
data = data.split('|')

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

if form.getvalue('prev'):
        if(cur > 1):
        cur = int (cookie["Current"].value) - 1
    cookie["Current"] = cur

print cookie
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
```

HTML CODE

```
print   "<span id=\"disQ\">" 
print   data[0] 
print   "</span></br>"
print   "<input  type=\"radio\"  name=\"qstn\" value=\"1\" /><span>" + data[1] + "</span></br>"
print   "<input  type=\"radio\"  name=\"qstn\" value=\"2\" /><span>" + data[2] + "</span></br>"
print   "<input  type=\"radio\"  name=\"qstn\" value=\"3\" /><span>" + data[3] + "</span></br>"
print   "<input  type=\"radio\"  name=\"qstn\" value=\"4\" /><span>" + data[4] + "</span></br>"

print   "<input id=\"prev\" name=\"prev\" type=\"submit\" value=\"PREV\" onclick=\"this.form.submit()\">"
print   "<input id=\"next\" name=\"next\" type=\"submit\" value=\"NEXT\" onclick=\"this.form.submit()\">"

print   "<h5>Total Questions : </h5><span class = \"data\" id=\"total\">"+ cookie["Count"].value + "</span>"
print   "<h5>Attempted :</h5><span class = \"data\" id=\"attempt\">" + cookie["Attempted"].value + "</span>"
print   "<h5>Correct :</h5><span class = \"data\" id=\"correct\">" + cookie["Correct"].value + "</span>"
print   "<h5>Wrong :</h5><span class = \"data\" id=\"wrong\">" + cookie["Wrong"].value + "</span>"
print   "<h5>Score :</h5><span class = \"data\" id=\"score\">" + cookie["Score"].value + "</span>"
```

Comment: You should really look at `htmltmpl`

Comment: Could you give us a sample of your question bank?

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you haven't put this within `<form>` tags. Do that and it will submit back to your server and you can work with it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the htmltmpl reference i'll see to it.

and yes my html is inside <form>

Question back contains some sample questions...eg.
Who won Lusofonia Games 2014?|Portugal|Angola|India|Brazil|3

Comment: When i click on Submit button, Nothing happens.I am stuck here with the logic.
i got these errors in console
*The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. mQuiz.cgi
*TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null quiz.js:7
*TypeError: next is not a function

Comment: Weird, I don't get that error when I run it on my computer. Is there more code to this that isn't posted?

Comment: More Code meaning rest is the layout stuff.. from which i have put up the html of what i am debugging on.

Comment: yeah you may want to post the specific error in another post.